# Should shma be read in the special trop?

Tags: shema, trop-cantillation, high-holidays

On the Yamim Noraim, a special trop is used for reading the Torah. For someone who generally reads shma with the trop, would it be preferable to use the special trop if possible?

I ask because generally, we use one trop "mode" for Torah reading throughout the day. Shma is said with the Torah trop because that's where it's from. Do we use the mode of the day here, or might we use different modes for leining and shma?

Comment: On Tisha Bav should they read it with Eicha trop?

Comment: @DoubleAA If the Torah is read with Eicha trop, then the question would apply to that as well.

Comment: If oyu could indicate why you think the Trop used to read the Torah specifically that day should be relevant that would improve your question.

Comment: I know of lots of days when we use multiple trop modes, such as Shabbat, Purim, Shavuot, Shabbat Chol HaMoed and Tisha Bav (we use three on the latter 3!).

Comment: Yes, we have different modes for different things. One for Torah, one for Haftarah, one for Megillah. But as i said, only one for Torah, throughout the day.

Comment: Actually you didn't say that. Nor did you explain why you think you hsould limit yourself to Torah. Furthermore, some places use different modes for different parts of the Torah reading on Shabbat Chazon, fast days and/or Simchat Torah.

Comment: Hopefully it's a little better now. I limit to Torah reading because that's what Shma is. I did not know about customs changing the modes on those days that you mentioned.

Comment: The special trop is clearly only used for the High Holiday's keriyas haTorah. If Rosh Hashana falls out on Shabbos and we need to read the Torah at mincha, and on Yom Kippur when we read the Torah at mincha, we don't use the special trop. (Lehalakha, though, you can read Shema with whatever tune you like)

Comment: Isn't the trop for the day used for the unique readings for the day? On R"H that might encompass all the public readings (maybe). But on Simhath Torah it is only for some of the readings. On 9 Av there are some parts read in "Eicha Trop" and some not. On Purim, similarly. Why would you assume that this would fit that category of special reading?

Comment: And why do you assume Shema' needs to be read with any trop?

Comment: @SethJ Many, including me, read the shma with trop. ArtScroll says this is commendable.